# What type of wood panels could replace the glass in a storm door?

Tags: repair, doors

A couple of days ago I opened the inside door and the full view window in my storm door shattered and fell onto the living room floor. I have been considering replacing the window with a wood panel. I do scroll fretwork as a hobby and was thinking of doing some panels with a frame that replaces the window part of the door.

What wood would you recommend for the frame and panels?

Comment: Storm doors take a lot of thermal abuse, and I wouldn't imagine a wood one would last all that long, especially one made of lots of pieces. And, I personally love my full view storm door. (Since you asked my opinion...)

Comment: Fretwork will give you none of the thermal/weather-resistance characteristics that are presumably why a storm door was installed in the first place. And the fretwork won't give you the kind of view that glass does, of course. I love the idea of a large carved panel, but even if this is where you want it, I'd suggest finding a way to mount it inside the glass and/or screen.

Answer (score 1):

Redwood is widely available, it has excellent weather-ability, and it is easily shaped and cut.